# What do we define as "surroundings" in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was thinking about the 2nd law of thermodynamics, and how ΔS<sub>total</sub>=ΔS<sub>system</sub>+ΔS<sub>surrounding</sub>.

You could potentially have a reaction with negative ΔS<sub>total</sub> occurring- a non-spontaneous reaction.

But by the 2nd law, ΔS<sub>universe</sub> , which a teacher defined as ΔS<sub>total</sub> or ΔS<sub>system</sub>+ΔS<sub>surrounding</sub> , should always increase.

An example of a non-spontaneous reaction would be electrolysis of water- I read that it is so as water would remain water forever and not decompose on its own. Would this decomposition not be a non-spontaneous process, thus violating the 2nd law?

Comment: Well, you are right: non-spontaneous reactions don't occur, as they violate the Second Law. As for the apparent contradiction, this may lend some insight: what kind of non-spontaneous reactions are you thinking of that occur in the real world?

Comment: It is possible to carry out a reaction of ideal gases reversibly, at constant temperature and pressure, and, in such a case, the sum of the entropy changes of the system and surroundings is zero.  Google Van't Hoff equilibrium box.

Comment: The second sentence makes an incorrect assumption, therefore the premise of your line of argumentation is flawed.

Comment: @orthocresol Ah, I read somewhere that certain reactions were coupled with others as they are non-spontaneous. Would a reaction like this count as a non-spontaneous reaction?


Sorry for this maybe basic question, I've just started learning thermodynamics.

Comment: I think the duplicate question will help you.